# Please reopen the star-wars laser fire question as it is nowhere close to a duplicate

Tags: duplicate-questions, vote-to-reopen, discussion

This question about the significance of laser colours in Star Wars was closed as a duplicate:

[What is the significance of the reversed colours of imperial and rebellion lasers compared to lightsabers?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/33080/2565)

And this is the proposed duplicate:

[Why are the colors reversed between the blasters and lightsabers of the Republic/Rebels and Empire?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/8796/2565)

Now, if you carefully (or at all) read the questions, you will see that the now-closed one is asking about behind-the-scenes ("what is the significance") while the other one is asking for the "quality of gas" retcon.

The answers to the older question do not address the out-of-universe either, as far as I could tell.

Did I overlook something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The question was never closed

As you can see from the post's [timeline](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/33080/timeline), the question was not at any time closed as a duplicate.

Yes, there were some 'proposed' close votes, but it was [voted to leave open](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/close/115209) by three reviewers.

[image]

It was good of you to update your question to further limit the scope and add clarification, but don't fret, there seems to have been nothing wrong with the question, and it was never closed.

Comment: My bad, it looked closed to me. But there is still a note in the top, suggesting that is (or in stack-exchange lingo "might be") a dupe.

Am I the only one seeing this?

https://i.imgur.com/jqEwmZy.png

Comment: @bitmask that's a note to the post's author (visible only to you).

Comment: @Kevin Thanks. Clearly I've been away from StackExchange too long.